# OS missing from computer after update

Tags: windows-10

I have a computer that came with win 10 when it was new, after a windows update bricked my computer there was no OS on it.  I did a clean install but found out the copy wasn't legit so now I have to buy a windows disk from a store and if so do i buy win 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sure does not save any money. Best source now is a License from the Microsoft Store. Go there and purchase a license for Windows 10.

When you get it, right click on Computer to get Properties.

In the screen that comes up, you can click on the Change Product Key link, enter the purchased key and activate.

In future, and in most cases indeed, once Windows 10 is properly licensed, you can reinstall it, including replacing the disk.

I am not entirely sure what happened but I trust all is well now.

Comment: My computer came with OS installed, but it was ruined by win update. So then a friend loaned me a flash drive with windows 10 on it, but it isn't legit. So I will have to buy a disc

Comment: thank you btw for taking the time to answer

Comment: @janesdean - If Windows came with your computer, then you don't need another license, Windows 10 will automatically detect the imbedded license within your ACPI table upon installation.  If the installation is not activated then you likely installed a different edition then you have a license for.

Comment: the thing is i did a complete clean install (fdisk) and there was nothing on it when i installed the bad copy

Comment: i am going to go ahead and buy a new disc, just hated to when the computer i have came with it installed. but my own fault  thanks so much for the answers

Comment: That sounds like a decent plan. Best wishes.